Sublattice isomorphisms
Let $L$ be a non-distributive complete (bounded) lattice with the greatest element $1$ and the smallest element $0$.
Definitions: For a given $x,y\in L$, let's use the notation $[x,y] := \{z\in L: x\leq z\leq y\}$. Clearly $[x,y]$ is a sublattice of $L$.
Let's say that a lattice isomorphism $\phi:[x_1,y_1]\to [x_2,y_2]$ extends to or has an extension $\Phi:L\to L$ if $\Phi$ is a lattice isomorphism and its restriction $\Phi|_{[x_1,y_1]}$ is equal to $\phi$.
Suppose whenever there are isomorphisms $\phi:[0,x]\to[0,y]$ and $\psi:[x,1]\to[y,1]$, there exists an extension $\Psi:L\to L$ that extends both $\phi$ and $\psi$ simultaneously. If $L$ satisfies this property, let's say that $L$ is extension symmetric.

Question: I'm looking for characterizations of extension symmetric lattices.

It would also be great to know particular representations and/or examples of such lattices. In the distributive case, the Stone representation theorem and its variants are surely of great help.

Notes: 1. Complete lattices are precisely the injective objects in the category of posets with monotone maps [BB1967]. So, given $\phi$ & $\psi$ as above, There always exists a monotone map $\Psi$ that extends $\phi$ & $\psi$ simultaneously. However, we may not guarantee that $\Psi$ is actually an isomorphism.

An example: Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. The lattice of closed subspaces of $H$ is an extension symmetric non-distributive complete lattice. For any two closed subspaces $V,W\subseteq H$, meet and join are defined by $V\wedge W = V\cap W$ and $V\vee W = \overline{V + W}$. This lattice is even complemented, where $\neg V
:=V^{\perp}$ the orthogonal complement of $V$.


(Side question): Every bounded total order is extension symmetric, and not all of them are complete.

@KeithKearnes Thanks, my mind must have been wandering somewhere else. $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ is an easy non-complete counterexample. I edit the post to remove the side-question.

Can you give an example not totally ordered?

The powerset of a set.

I get it because there aren't ``many isomorphisms'' (from order interval to one going up chain). cool.  But how about an order interval in a Banach lattice. Heaps of isomorphisms going up chain and if I'm quickly reading the definition right, only one dimensional space satisfies extension symmetry?????
